# TypeError: 'Transaction' object is not iterable in Flask on Python 3.6

Tags: python, marshmallow, marshmallow-sqlalchemy

I am trying to use a serializer to store my JSON data into DB. I have created an API and using in postman. Like :

POST endpoint: `API/transaction` and data with `JSON` format

Where I load into serializer it returns an error. I tested in the shell too. I am not getting an exact error in the debug tool.

my serializer is:

```
class TransactionSerializer(ma.ModelSchema):
    """transaction validation"""
    partner_client_id = fields.String(required=True)
    agent_id = fields.String(required=True)
    agent_msisdn = fields.String(required=True)
    code = fields.Integer(required=True)
    title = fields.String(required=False)
    price = fields.String(required=True)
    currency = fields.String(required=False)
    user_msisdn = fields.String(required=True)
    requested_ip = fields.String(required=False)
    platform = fields.String(required=False)
    is_recurring = fields.Boolean(required=False)

    class Meta:
        """Meta class."""
        model = Transaction
```

Here is python SHELL

```
>>> from app.serializer.transaction_serializer import TransactionSerializer
>>> transaction_serializer = TransactionSerializer()

>>> trn_json ={
...     "partner_client_id": "CLIENTID009",
...     "agent_id": "agent222",
...     "agent_msisdn": "8801831803255",
...     "code": "10",
...     "title": "10 Days Unlimited ",
...     "price": "10.00",
...     "currency": "BDT",
...     "user_msisdn": "8801925533362",
...     "requested_ip": "127.0.0.1",
...     "platform": "universal",
...     "is_recurring": True
... }


>>> trn_json
{'partner_client_id': 'CLIENTID009', 'agent_id': 'agent222', 'agent_msisdn': '8801831803255', 'code': '10', 'title': '10 Days Unlimited ', 'price': '10.00', 'currency': 'BDT', 'user_msisdn': '8801925533362', 'requested_ip': '127.0.0.1', 'platform': 'universal', 'is_recurring': True}

>>> transaction, errors = transaction_serializer.load(trn_json)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>

TypeError: 'Transaction' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Maybe `transaction_serializer.load()` returns the `Transaction` object, not a `transaction, error` 2-tuple (or any other iterable of 2)?

Comment: @IljaEverilä, woldn't this yield a `TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable Transaction object`? Anyway, this is easy enough to test. Just print the output of load and its type.

Comment: @Jérôme .. okay.

Comment: @Jérôme I can not print `type(transaction)` when the error occurs

Comment: @IljaEverilä this error occurs when I use `transaction, errors = transaction_serializer.load(trn_json)` but it works with this `transaction = transaction_serializer.load(trn_json)`

Comment: @Jérôme At least in Python 3.6, no: `a, b = object()` leads to `TypeError: 'object' object is not iterable`.

Comment: @SelimReza So the issue is just that: `load()` returns the deserialized transaction, not a pair of transaction, error.

Comment: @Jérôme what will be the solution in `python 3.6` ?

Comment: Don't try to unpack the result, it's the transaction.

Comment: @IljaEverilä what do you suggest? only `transaction`? then how do I get `errors` ?

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html. Python uses exceptions quite often.

Comment: @IljaEverilä OK. I had just checked with PY3.7 and had a different message, so I assumed the error might lie elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to unpack the result of the loading as (result, error) tuple. This is what you would do with marshmallow 2.

With marshmallow 3, loading and dumping either output the result (no error) or raise an exception. This is equivalent to marshmallow 2 when the schema has `strict=True` meta option. See [Upgrading to 3.0 - Schemas are always strict](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/upgrading.html#schemas-are-always-strict).

My guess is you're using marshmallow 3 (which is great) but the marshmallow 2 way.

Please try

```
try:
    transaction = transaction_serializer.load(trn_json)
except ma.ValidationError as err:
    errors = err.messages
    valid_data = err.valid_data
```

If you copied the tuple unpacking code from some documentation, you may want to ping the author for an update.

Comment: Yes, this works. it there any best practice with `__init__` or `decorator` for all models ?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Maybe you can clarify it and make it a question on its own.

Comment: I meant, is there any best option to use all input data validation globally?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, @Jerome great solution. Works for me.

I was getting TypeError: 'ValidationError' object is not a mapping

I had to do:

```py
except ValidationError as e:
    raise CustomException(message=e.messages, status_code=400)
```

Without the messages attribute of the error (e), marshmallow throws the result as a tuple of a list of messages and status code.